# android, Everyone should evaluate each day only once

Tags: java, android, sdk, unique, uniqueidentifier

I'm going to build an app. Until now everything runs very well. Now I have a problem. The app gets its content from a mysql database.A column is called item.I have a ratingbar. The user can rate the item there.Every time the user evaluates an item the value is stored on the database in the respective item line.The values ​​are then added. In other words, when a user evaluates 20 times with 5 stars, the value adds up to 100 and so on.
I want to limit this. I will that the user can evaluate each day only once an item. I will it without a registration mask for the user. How can I solve this problem?

I know that i can identifier the WIFI MAC Adreess and other Unique Identifiers, but how can i solve this with them?

I can not use sqlite database, because the items should update with the time from the mysql database.

A registration mask should not be excluded. If this process is quite possible with them, then I supplement it with it.

I am looking forward to every comment

Comment: Simply overwrite the user's insertion (i.e.: by using `REPLACE INTO`). So that each insertion will replace the previous one. And there will be only one for each user on a date.

Answer (score 0):

every computer has a machine ID, you will hash that and encrypt that to use as your identifier..most telecomms do not like using MAc addresses as IDs

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create UUID during every installation and sending this UUID to your server along with every request. In server, you can control very well if user can provide feedback once a day or others based on your requirement. Pls refer this link on how to create UUID.
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html